# How to customize dropdown item in react semantic-ui-react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using dropdown from semantic-ui-react.
I am dynamically creating a dropdown option, and I want to change the background color of the item dynamically.
How can I fill the background color to 100%?
[image]

```js
Campaign

import {
  Dropdown,
  Menu,
} from "semantic-ui-react";
//make customize option
  getCustomerGroupOptions = () => {
    let options = [
      {
        text: "none",
        key: "none",
        value: {},
      },
    ];
   for (let tag of this.props.tags || []) {
      options = [
        ...options,
        {
          text: tag.label,
          key: tag.id,
          value: tag,
          content: (
            <div
              className="item"
              style={{ backgroundColor: tag.color, color: "#fff" }}
            >
              {tag.label}
            </div>
          ),
        },
      ];
    }
}
    

//Dropdown
                  <Dropdown
          error={errors.recipientFlag}
          placeholder={I18n.get(
            `${scope}.normalModal.title3.group.placeholder`
          )}
          className="mb-5 width-75 max-width-350px"
          name="recipient"
          value={campaign.recipient ? campaign.recipient : null}
          selection
          options={groupOptions}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use inspector, you'll find that the css you're overriding is only set to the `div.item.text` element. It's a lot easier to get what you want if you just set the css to `div.item` created by `semantic-ui-react`.

Use `Dropdown.Item` and set your css to that component. I've removed some stuff for which you didn't provide logic, but you can interpolate from something like this:

```
import {
    Dropdown
  } from "semantic-ui-react";
const Campaign = (props) => {
    const getCustomerGroupOptions = () => {
      let options = [
      ];
     for (let tag of props.tags || []) {
        options = [...options,
              <Dropdown.Item
                style={{ backgroundColor: tag.color, color: "#fff"}}
              >
                {tag.label}
              </Dropdown.Item>
        ];
      }

      return options;
  }
  
  return (
         <Dropdown
            className="mb-5 width-75 max-width-350px"
            placeholder='Select Friend'
            name="recipient"
            selection
          >
              <Dropdown.Menu>
                {getCustomerGroupOptions()}
              </Dropdown.Menu>
          </Dropdown>
    );
}

export default Campaign;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you so much:)Thanks I solved the problem.  
Do you know how to give opacity when each item is hovered?